# An efficient way to get dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follwos:

```
           City     Name
    0   Seattle    Alice
    1   Seattle      Bob
    2  Portland  Mallory       
    3  Portland      Bob
```

What is an efficient way to get a dictionary for which the keys are cities and the values are names, i.e.:

```
dict = {'Seattle': {'Alice','Bob'}, 'Portland': {'Mallory','Bob'}}
```

I was thinking about using df.groupby('City')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.apply` and `to_dict`:

```
df.groupby('City')['Name'].apply(set).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.groupby('City')` is an iterator. You can use it in a dict comprehension to generate the desired dict:

```
In [84]: {city:set(grp['Name'].tolist()) for city, grp in df.groupby('City')}
Out[84]: {'Portland': {'Bob', 'Mallory'}, 'Seattle': {'Alice', 'Bob'}}
```

---

To create a DataFrame with sets in the Name column, you could use `groupby/apply`:

```
In [91]: df.groupby('City')['Name'].apply(set).reset_index()
Out[91]: 
       City            Name
0  Portland  {Bob, Mallory}
1   Seattle    {Alice, Bob}
```

Comment: Thanks, another question, can I put the dictionary into a framework? with columns City and Name. but in the name column I would have a set, e.g. {'Bob', 'Mallory'}.?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
dict(df.groupby('City')['Name'].apply(list))
```